# Sharepoint 2013: Need pop-up message to appear as soon as a user updates a list field value to 2 particular values

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

How can I get a `pop-up message` (which reminds the user to launch a url) to appear as soon as a user `updates a list field value` to 2 particular values?  We are using `SharePoint 2013`. Thanks

Comment: I'm not experienced in coding, so I'd be grateful for some step by step guidance on how to do this in Sharepoint please.

Comment: Then you have to get experienced with coding: [PreSaveAction Helps for Actions before Saving an Item](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/06/sharepoint-presaveaction-helps-for-actions-before-saving-an-item/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SharePoint's `PreSaveAction()` where you can check for the values and create a popup. This function is automatically called when user try to save an item. Below are the steps to use it:

1. Add a script editor webpart on your page
2. Write the below code in it and save

jQuery is optional though you'll always need to return true or false depending on the check you are trying.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
 function PreSaveAction() { 
 var txtTitle = j(":input[title='Title']").val(); 
   alert(txtTitle);
   if(txtTitle == ''){        
   alert("Please enter a title");   //write popup code here       
   return false;
}
else{
   return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with a code base solution then you can create a custom event event receiver. You can have a  `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to show the pop up in the ItemAdded Method.